# seamless mode remote desktop connection from linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, remote, seamless

I am a programmer using Linux as my main OS, however sometimes I need to use windows (ie, office, ea). 
I'm running qemu with kvm to access the windows "machine".

I would like to achieve something that is described here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SeamlessVirtualization
(It means I would be able to run chosen applications on Windows and then display them locally on Linux as separate windows achieving good desktop integration).

However seamless rdp is buggy and doesn't work on my machine (probably because I'm using a tiling window manager and a 64bit system).

Are you aware of any other solution then rdp seamless mode?  I would prefer to still use quemu because it uses cpu hardware virtualization, so different protocol/client combination would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only very recently that there has been support for single windows via RDP, I don't think this has been implemented yet in xrdp - and requires a server licence at the MS end. AFAIK VNC and NoMachine NX still don't provide the functionality. It has been available in Citrix for a long time (and there are free Linux clients available).

Comment: I searched the xrdp mailing lists and it says it maybe could work with seamless rdp. Still rdesktop gives me core dump. I think I'll have to compile and debug it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Virtualbox, a free and open-source software for managing virtual machines. It used to be owned by Sun until it was acquired by Oracle - I use it myself, it's pretty good.

Either way, once your Windows VM is installed, there is a seemless mode integration. You can look at this screenshot to have an idea - except this screenshot is a Mac host with a Windows guest in seemless mode.
http://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/wiki/Screenshots/VirtualBox_OSX_beta_3.png

Best of luck,

Comment: Yes, I have been using it when I was kde user, but unfortunately the seamless mode didn't work well in the window manager I currently use. I also don't like the start menu being constantly on the screen.
I would give you upvote, but I don't have that possibility yet.